# SQL Developer Regexp_Like search for phrase within long string

Tags: sql, oracle

All,

I am trying to search for a phrase ("Observed TRD3 Ufls" within a long string, and I am having trouble. Sometimes the sub string could be at the beginning, sometimes in the middle, and sometimes at the end. I am trying to something like

```
    MAX(CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(B.shipment,'Observed TRD3 Ufls','i') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY d.Status) AS Tag
```

Sometimes observed can be observe so I need to be able to get both, and lastly it needs to be case insensitive.

Every result I review is always 0 instead of 1.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `REGEXP`, You can simply use the like as follows:

```
upper(B.shipment) LIKE '%OBSERVED TRD3 UFLS%'
```

Please note that It is working fine for me even if the matching string is at the start, middle, or end of the column

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I will add an or LIKE '%OBSERVE TRD3 UFLS%' to catch the others.

Comment: @AwFawk This would also match `UNOBSERVED TRD3 UFLSAAA` which may not be what you want.

Comment: That can be handled with the spaces at the start and end of the matching string.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your current regex logic should appear in a `where` clause:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(shipment, 'Observed TRD3 Ufls', 'i');
```

Your current call to `REGEXP_LIKE` should already be doing a case insensitive search for the text.  Note that strictly speaking, if you want to find the exact text `Observed TRD3 Ufls` inside the text, you should be using word boundaries:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(shipment, '(^|\s)Observed TRD3 Ufls(\s|$)', 'i');
```

This will match the text at the start, middle, or end.

Comment: This did not work on the case statement. :( I have other criterias on the where so gotta use case when to tag these instances.

Comment: You didn't ask a complete question, because you didn't show the full query or any data.  And, as a result, it appears that I haven't given a complete answer.  No surprises here.

Comment: As a beginner I appreciate your kindness. Thanks for trying, and my apologies.